# Google firebase messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 follow this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1,

This is my code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
(async () => {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential:  admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  });

  const message = {
    data: {
      time: '1:15 PM',
      symbol: 'GOOG',
      value: '1184.46'
    },
    token: 'cc2oO0V9TzSLsl3IzVlc3Z:APA91bEXOhTVA-nU9-zIiRTSOjL6q9YnOxNCCw21C8ymd_0xkJ64PvUO4ml2Gfe8gNX8pN9ruMMu-dFQplr0-zkn6iJPuiqqNqeRoHjrWmWNWibPtIsCIGm9Yj0dI1OZUVAnHFKNKiZ5',
  };
  const messageId = await admin.messaging().send(message);
  console.log(messageId);
})();
```

I also generated new private key in the firebase console and set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, but once I run this code, it would get stuck for a long time without output and then report an error：

```
(node:28659) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: connect ETIMEDOUT 142.251.42.237:443.".
    at /Users/xiaofei/Desktop/assaa/AAECO/My/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-app.js:85:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async /Users/xiaofei/Desktop/assaa/AAECO/My/OpenSourceProjects/FCM.js:87:21
```

I tried a lot of things, but nothing worked

Comment: This answer fixed my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43107493/firebase-nodejs-behind-proxy-server?rq=2